# Can we use Android CameraX for Image Processing?

Tags: android, image-processing, android-camerax

I have heard about Android's new camera library called CameraX.  So, I read some articles about it and walked through the official CameraX Codelab.

This library has a ImageAnalysis class for processing incoming frames from the Preview.

The examples presented were very basic.

What I wanted to know is that if that class could also be used for a real-time image processing like changing the colour of the incoming frame to grey, apply blur effects etc.

If so, could I also combine it with render-script for a faster image processing ?

I ask because I started building a real-time image processing camera app but since camera2 API was too complicated I gave up.

CameraX seems to be nicer, so I would like to restart that homeproject again.

Comment: IDK about camerax image processing if u didn't get anything, use OPENCV. It'll help.

Comment: Any work around?